# Access Reveal Modal from within a jquery library

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5, zurb-reveal

I'm trying to modify a jquery form validation plugin, so I can show a reveal-modal once I get the ajax response.

I managed to access the object with `window.Foundation`, and even fire the `open` event with `window.Foundation.libs.reveal.open($target)`.

The problem is that, at this point, the modal backdrop appears but not the modal itself.

Is there a way to fire the event properly?

Thanks,